# Does knowing the generators and the orders of those generators of a finite group $G$ completely determine $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Does knowing the generators and the orders of those generators of a finite group $G$ completely determine $G$?

For instance, is there only one group $G$ generated by the elements $\{g,h\}$ where $|g|,|h| = 3$?

Comment: Perhaps up to isomorphism.

Comment: For the additional information needed to uniquely define a finite group in terms of its generators, you might be interested in the notion of [a group presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group).

Comment: @Chocolate Sorry but the Klein 4-gruppe **is** $C_2 \times C_2$ see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group).

Comment: @BogaertsMarc whoops well that was a dumb comment on my part!  Thanks >_<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be more than one group with the same number of generators and with the generators being of the same order. For example $Z_4\times Z_2$ and $D_8$ both have two generators, one of order $2$ and one of order $4$.

Occasionally this information will point to a single group, but not always.

Comment: Thanks. What extra information would be needed to completely determine the group then?

Comment: @JoshuaLin there are a lot of ways you can completely determine a finite group. The most straightforward is to give the multiplication table for the entire group. To see more concise methods, this might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group

Comment: @JoshuaLin:  An idea of the lack of uniqueness, even when the order of the *commutator* of the two generators is known, can be gathered from the paper "Groups Defined by the Order of Two Generators and the Order of their Commutator" by [G. A. Miller (1908)](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1908-009-01/S0002-9947-1908-1500803-4/S0002-9947-1908-1500803-4.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group): this group can be generated by an element of order $2$ and three elements of order $4$. The same can be said of $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$. The former is not Abelian, the latter is.

EDIT: In the example you gave, $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$ is of course one such group. There is another, albeit trivial case of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ where $g=1,h=2$. Both elements have order $3$, but these two groups are distinct. You could argue that this is cheating, since $\mathbb{Z}_3$ only needs one of those two generators, but you can still express it as $\mathbb{Z}_3=<g,h| g^3=h^3=gh=e>$